# python limit number of queries per 8 hours

Tags: python, time

Someone might have already solved this problem. I have a need for a Python based UDP interface which returns results from a DB query.  The DB is limited to providing only 500 queries per 8 hour period.  Here is my logic it seems to sort of work.

But I really have a moving windows of 8 hours which means I can soon query the DB within a few seconds.  I am right at the limit basically.  Anyone has a clever reuseable code I can use for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SocketServer
import sys,os,httplib,urllib,multiprocessing,time
import syslog
import sqlite3 as lite
syslog.openlog(sys.argv[0],syslog.LOG_PID,syslog.LOG_USER)
count_d=0
stime=int(time.time())

def oprocess(vars):
    global count_d,stime
    dtime=int(time.time())-stime
    score="Unknown"
    if count_d > 500:
        if dtime < 28800:
            syslog.syslog("Exceeded q limit "+str(dtime)+","+str(count))
            return "Unknown"
        else: # Reset the clock
            stime=time.time()
            count_d=0
    data=dbh.do("SELECT...") # Some DB query
    if data != None:
        count_d=count_d+1
        return data
```

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Why do you need to do the counting? Doesn't whatever imposes the limit do the counting? Just catch the exception of the failed query.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a global list of successful query times in `qlist`, and then inside oprocess():

```
def oprocess(vars):
    global qlist
    now = int(time.time())
    #remove queries older than 8 hours
    while qlist:
        if now - qlist[0] > 28800:
            del qlist[0]
        else:
            break 
    if len(qlist) < 500:
        #you are good to go
        #submit your query, then append the time to qlist
        data=dbh.do("SELECT...") # Some DB query
        qlist.append(int(time.time()))
```

Comment: This solution is similar to Fraggy's solution and will work - only little concern I have is keeping a large qlist/queries in memory.  All I kind of care about is the counter/8 hr in a way.  I thought about having just one counter and a start_time variable as global variables.  Check if counter is < limit and difftime (now-start_time) is < 28800. If not, don't query the DB.  If okay, add counter and query DB.  When difftime > 28800 reset start_time to current time and counter to 0.  Makes sense?

Comment: 500 ints does not consume a lot of memory. You are just saving the timestamps, not the queries themselves.

Answer (score 0):

keep all timestamps in a list and filter then on every query. Or rely on the upstream to block you and handle the exception

```
import time

queries = []
INTERVAL = 8*24*60
MAX_QUERIES = 500


def do_query():
    global queries
    now = time.time()
    # filter query timestamps
    queries = filter(lambda x: now-x < INTERVAL, queries)
    if len(queries) < MAX_QUERIES:
        # do query
        queries.append(now)
    else:
        raise Exception("too man queries")
```